# TS cannot find my vue3 module ' or its corresponding type declarations error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

Hi I stuck on this error and can´t find the way how to solve it. Both files are in the same directory: ...assets\article-area\

```
[tsl] ERROR in C:\www\office\assets\article-area\index.ts(2,18)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './Test.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
 @ ./assets/index.ts 12:14-45
```

My index.ts

```
import {createApp} from "vue";
import Test from "./Test.vue";

export default () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".article-edit-area-select").forEach((root: HTMLElement) => {
        let app= createApp(Test);
        app.mount(root);
    });
}
```

My Test.vue

```
<template>
Test
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default {
  name: "Test",

}
</script>
```

I have suspicious that this error happend becouse of bad settings of my tsconfig.json maybe? But not sure what exactly is bad.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "assets/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Webpack.config

```
...
  module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(styl|stylus)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // 'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'stylus-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // 'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                type: "asset/resource"
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

I also have to say that code compile and works in browser but npm run watch output me the error above. :/

Comment: This is specific to the rest of the config, which isn't shown, more specifically Vue loader. The question has webpack label but it's not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry i´ve edited and added webpack config. There could be problem too ofc and probably it is in webpack config I think.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing the following in a src/shims-vue.d.ts file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```